# flex-wrap not growing and overflowing on chrome

Tags: css, google-chrome, flexbox

I have a complex nested flex layout mixed with some bootstrap rows and columns.

Everything looks good except this particular code:

```
<div style="display: flex; flex-wrap: wrap;">

    <!-- Fixed 350px width -->
    <div style="flex: 0 0 350px;">
        <div style="width: 300px; height: 400px; background: green;">         </div>
    </div>

    <!-- flexible div that should not shrink below 360px -->
    <div style="flex: 1 1360px;">
        ...some content...
    </div>

</div>
```

What I expected was for the 2 children to wrap, one on top of the other, and the parent to grow to accomodate both.

**Very important**: this only happens when I shrink the window after the site is already loaded. If I open the site with the window already shrunken, the site renders as expected.

This works on IE and Firefox, but looks very bad on chrome.

Pictures are worth a thousand words:

Normal flow, before wrap[image: 1]

After wrapping on chrome[image: 2]

Expected result (IE)[image: 3]]

Does anybody have any idea why is Chrome behaving this way, or what's wrong with the code?

Full example: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/PdPmxv

Comment: Would be helpful if we could reproduce the problem. Consider posting an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Done, just access the codepen link at the bottom.

Comment: The codepen behaves the same in FF and Chrome.

Comment: you have to open the codepen, then shrink the window

Comment: That's exactly what I did. Identical behavior at all screen sizes in both browsers.

Comment: I cannot tell you why by adding `flex-shrink:0` fix the issue : https://jsfiddle.net/q6zt70mc/ ... the layout is somehow complex and no more energy to deep into it actually